# Vue 2.5 template with Webpack and Typescript

Tags: typescript, vuejs2, vuex

The documentation says that a vue-cli template for typescript is comming soon, but currently none is availible. The official vue guide only shows a recommended tsconfig.json file.

I assume there's lots of additional work getting the all the magic inside webpack to play. And using an old starterkit based on an outdated version of webpack will, based on previous projects, give me hours of future headache.

So, If somebody already have gone through the trouble of creating a vue/vuex/webpack/typescript I'd be really happy if you could share it.

Thanks

Comment: I tried my best to get types working but with no luck at all. They are just falling apart when I change `<script>` to `<script lang="ts">`. Going to wait official vue-cli template I guess.

Comment: Haven’t tried Vue 2.5 yet, but 2.0 works for me when I include https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component and the Vetur plugin for VSCode

Answer (score 1):

I created a Vue project with TypeScript, webpack, vuex and [vue-component-class](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component).

It's for my friend, so you can use it too.

1. Download the zip file from my google drive [zip](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0BwAlkn2For1bWXBTcEVBWGZTZGc?usp=sharing).
2. npm install
3. Open your browser.
4. http://localhost:3443

Comment: Thanks. But I got the understanding the 2.5 release should remove the need for vue-component-class? Maybe I read it wrong? https://medium.com/the-vue-point/upcoming-typescript-changes-in-vue-2-5-e9bd7e2ecf08

Comment: To accompany the export syntax change, the following core libraries that have typings relying on Vue core typing will receive new major versions, and should be upgraded along with Vue core 2.5: vuex, vue-router, vuex-router-sync, vue-class-component.

in case of vue-class-component is 6.0.0V its very easy and good library...

Answer (score 1):

Well, I feel the release of the official vue-cli template is close. But since I have no clue how close it is, maybe yu can start with ducksoupdev's template here (and good news, it says it is already for Vue@2.5):

https://github.com/ducksoupdev/vue-webpack-typescript

Apparently, it does not contain vuex initializations, but can be a good starting point. All in all, the actual official templates do not include vuex neither.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this boilerplate provided by Microsoft called: TypeScript Vue Starter. Simply you can run:

```
npm install --save-dev typescript webpack ts-loader css-loader vue vue-loader vue-template-compiler
```

And add web pack configuration from documentation to get started.

You can find it [Here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Vue-Starter)